# Accessing linux server from java program and run TCL scripts stored on the linux server

Tags: java, linux, authentication, tcl, telnet

I know this is kind of specific and I need to find answers by dividing the question in to sub-questions. But I want to know the optimal way to do the same.

I have a linux server where I have my own login. There are some TCL scripts stored on the linux server.
I want to write a java program that I will be invoking from my windows machine, which should connect to the linux server once I provide my login name, password and hostname and should execute the scripts from the directory where the scripts are stored.

What I tried was (Found it on net) as below. This way it takes a lot of time to connect and to execute the simple commands like "ls". Also for running the scripts, I need to set some environment variables which I was able to set but I am not able to execute the script even after I gave execute permission on it.

```
static String executeCommand(Session session, String command)

            throws Exception {
        ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
        channel.setCommand(command);
        channel.setInputStream(null);
        channel.setErrStream(System.err);
        channel.connect();

        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + '\n');
        }
        channel.disconnect();

        return sb.toString();
    }

private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    try {
                JSch jsch = new JSch();
                System.out.println("Logging in");

            Session session = jsch.getSession("login name", "host name", port);

            session.setPassword("password");

                java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);

            session.connect();
            System.out.println("Logged in");

            System.out.println("==>" + executeCommand(session, "ls"));

        //System.out.println("==>" + executeCommand(session, "./first"));   

            Thread.sleep(60000);

            session.disconnect();
                System.out.println("Disconnected");  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

The shell script "first" has only below line

```
echo "First Script"
sh testscripts/assignment1.scr
```

While the same script if I run from the SSH terminal I get the desired output and the TCL script runs correctly. But if I try to run it from program I am not able to run it and it gives error as

```
testscripts/assignment1.scr: line 3: /bin/tclsh: No such file or directory
testscripts/assignment1.scr: line 3: exec: /bin/tclsh: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Do you have to use Java + Telnet? It's a lot easier to create an ssh key with `ssh-keygen`, upload the public part to the server, then use `ssh username@server command` where command can be one of the executable Tcl scripts or a program/script that runs all the scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. No Telnet was not necessary here and have removed it. I will try what you just suggested. Please have a look again, I have edited some part.

Comment: When I set the environment variable "AUTOTEST" which is needed to run the TCL scripts here, the errors about tclsh went off. But still the TCL script is not executed. I can see the statement "First Script" echoed out but not the TCL script.

Comment: Looks like tclsh isn't installed in `/bin`, or at least not with exactly that name.

Comment: I am tring to set the AUTOTEST as below. When I do this the errors related to tclsh are gone but still the script is not executed. 

                    System.out.println("==>" + executeCommand(session, "echo AUTOTEST = /auto/iconatest/users/pedeshpa/ats5.2.0"));
             System.out.println("==>" + executeCommand(session, "./assignment1.scr"));


My Script is as below

#!/bin/sh
# \
exec $AUTOTEST/bin/tclsh "$0" ${1+"$@"}
puts "My TCL script"


Output is as below, 

==>AUTOTEST = /auto/iconatest/users/pedeshpa/ats5.2.0

==>

Comment: The java program executing ./assginment1.scr didnt return any output so not sure if the script was run or not. How can I check ?

Comment: Thankfully it worked after I gave absolute path for the tclsh instead of doing it with $AUTOTEST in my script. It should work with the environment variables as well though. Will create a new question for the same.

Comment: [New Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873587/linux-environment-variables-not-the-same-as-when-we-access-them-from-jsch-script)